# Return something in a method without hanging a winform

Tags: c#, winforms

My question is a little hard to explain.

I have an object doing something who need an interface in constructor :

```
public class Engine
{
  public Engine(IControler controler);
}
```

In this interface, there is a method who need something directly from the winform :

```
public class Controler : IControler
{
  private MyForm _hook;      

  public Controler(MyForm hook)
  {
    _hook = hook;
  }

  // So, the method should be like this :

  public int GetTheRightThing()  // method from interface
  {
    // return here the right thing from clicking on the winform
    return _hook.WaitForClickAndGetTheRightThing()        
  }
}
```

So, how can I implement the method "_hook.WaitForClickAndGetTheRightThing()" right ?
I really don't see how to implement it without hanging the form...

Comment: What do you mean by "hanging the form"?

Comment: I mean, I don't know how to implement the method WaitForClickAndGetTheRightThing because the method will have to wait in the middle for user intervention and then return the information. But while waiting, the Thread will be stuck  (sorry for my english).

Comment: @RonanLamour unless your method does something *heavy* in background, your form can't be hung out. User intervention should do something with dialog and that means your form can't be hung out, it's just waiting for the return from dialog. If you have other code running in the main UI thread, you can use some asynchronous method call.

Comment: @RonanLamour: In that case, I would suggest simplifying the code in your question to a simple method of `MyForm`. This has nothing to do with passing around an interface across several classes.

Comment: I understand your point and that's what I do normally. BUT, here I have an object with a method who need something from the user (by a click). Just like "int GetThing()". But this method is used by other things (like a console for example where you can just implement "Console.Readline()") so it can't be changed and I must implement this interface for the object to work (ctor). I should let the user click and then keep the result for when the method is called but I need it right when the method is called. Sorry, it look like hard to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

So how about this:

```
public void GetTheRightThing(Action<int> callback)  // method from interface
{
  // return here the right thing from clicking on the winform
  _hook.WaitForClickAndGetTheRightThing(callback)        
}
```

and in form implementation after you finish invoke

```
callback.Invoke(result);
```

Comment: That's what I did but my problem is on the implementation of waitforclickandgettherightthing. I don't know how to wait in the method and continue it after information has been done by the user

Comment: Yes. I don't know if I can pause the method waiting for user intervention on the WinForm.